# Android manifest problem with android.hardware.nfc

Tags: android

I would like to use the feature android.hardware.nfc but this feature is missing in Android Studio
I have no idea what should I do. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by missing in Android studio.. But to use this specific feature you would need to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

To your AndroidManifest.xml and set your minSDK value to at least 10

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc